# Representing gaussian variables by real scalars

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, means

Sometimes we may need to do qualitative analysis of multiple Gaussian variables $\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2),\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2),\ldots$.

A naive strategy would be to just compare their means for a very coarse idea of which Gaussian is performing how.

I am interested in knowing what are the other complex ways in which a single scalar real can be attributed to $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ that can give maximum qualitative idea about a Gaussian distributed variable w.r.t. any criteria people have studied for?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Describe the experiment one is doing (drawing how many variables from what distributions?) and what inferences one hopes for please.

Comment: Reading it a few more times I think i get what you're going for (though it could certainly be clearer). You may want to read about sufficient and ancillary statistics, which pertain to situations when all the information about a distribution can be isolated in a few values computed from the data

Comment: As this stands, this Questoion is indeed too vague to answer in a way that is likely to be useful--as @spaceisdarkgreen has Commented. Can you describe a particular application? "Any criteria people have studied" hardly focuses the mind. Maybe google 'entropy', 'Shannon information' and related topics you encounter from there.